# Automatically resize JInternalFrame according to the screen resolution

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am developing the MDI application. JFrame as main window and JInternalFrame as child windows. How can I make sure that my internal frame has to re-size automatically when I increase/decrease the screen resolution.

> Scenario: Internal frame is in restore mode and occupied the complete
>   desktop size.

Now when I increase the screen resolution, I am able to see the additional desktop area that is not occupied by the internal frame.

Is there any way to auto re-size the internal frame according to resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Internal frame is in restore mode and occupied the complete desktop size.

The point of `restore` mode is that the frame size doesn't automatically change. If you want it to automatically change then the frame should be in `maximize` mode.

If you want to override the default behaviour then you can try adding a ComponentListener to the desktop pane. Whenever it's size changes you can then loop through all the internal frames and manually resize them.